# C# RSA equivalent code to the C++ Crypto API

Tags: c#, c++, rsa

```
DWORD nSize;
LPBYTE lpData;
HCRYPTKEY hPublicKey;


nSize = ReadFromFile(lpszUserPublicKey, NULL);

if(nSize == -1)
    return FALSE;

lpData = new BYTE[nSize];

ReadFromFile(lpszUserPublicKey, lpData);

if(!CryptImportKey(hProv, lpData, nSize, NULL, 0, &hPublicKey)) {
    delete lpData;
    return FALSE;
}

Erase(lpData, nSize);

// Get the data size(&nSize)
if(!CryptExportKey(hKey, hPublicKey, SIMPLEBLOB, 0, NULL, &nSize))
    return FALSE;

lpData = new BYTE[nSize];

CryptExportKey(hKey, hPublicKey, SIMPLEBLOB, 0, lpData, &nSize);

if(WriteToFile(lpszLicenseFile, lpData, nSize) == -1) {
    delete lpData;
    return FALSE;
}

delete lpData;

return CryptDestroyKey(hPublicKey);
```

How would the above code be written in C#. I am particularily interested in the Crypto API calls. Note, the encryption method that is used is RSA

Comment: hope that helps : [How to generate key pairs, encrypt and decrypt data with CryptoAPI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/01/28/how-to-generate-key-pairs-encrypt-and-decrypt-data-with-cryptoapi.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/RSACryptoPad.aspx) codeproject article seems it fits your needs. As shown in the article, C# has a [RSACryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx) Class in System.Security.Cryptography to make things a little easier so you don't have to roll an entire solution and translate all of that code manually.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I know how to use the RSACryptoServiceProvider. But what are the equivalent methods on the RSACryptoServiceProvider class to the above Crypto API calls.

Comment: You can view all of that using .NET Reflector from http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/ :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article about **RSA** in **C++** and **C#** if you are interested.
It contains the **code** and all you need to know to have RSA working in both languages, exchanging keys and messages between them :).

You can find it here:
[Crypt in C++ and Decrypt in C# (and C++)](http://riccardotramma.com/2011/02/crypt-in-c-and-decrypt-in-c-and-c/)